# Backpropagation not working

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

I am writing code for a neural network with 2 hidden layers. Here is my code snippet:

```
for i in range(200):
    z1 = sigmoid(np.dot(W1, X_train) + b1)
    z2 = sigmoid(np.dot(W2, z1) + b2)
    z3 = sigmoid(np.dot(W3, z2) + b3)
    C = cost(z3, Y_train)
    print(C)

    d3 = - np.multiply(np.multiply(z3, 1-z3), (np.divide(Y_train, z3) - np.divide(1 - Y_train, 1 - z3)))
    dw3 = np.dot(d3, z2.T)
    db3 = np.sum(d3, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    d2 = np.multiply(np.dot(W3.T, d3), np.multiply(z2, 1-z2))
    dw2 = np.dot(d2, z1.T)
    db2 = np.sum(d2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    d1 = np.multiply(np.dot(W2.T, d2), np.multiply(z1, 1-z1))
    dw1 = np.dot(d1, X_train.T)
    db1 = np.sum(d1, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    W1 -= 0.005*dw1
    W2 -= 0.005*dw2
    W3 -= 0.005*dw3
    b1 -= 0.005*db1
    b2 -= 0.005*db2
    b3 -= 0.005*db3
```

Cost function:

```
def cost(p, y):
    loss = -(np.multiply(y, np.log(p)) + np.multiply((1 - y), np.log(1 - p)))
    c = np.sum(loss)*1.0 / p.shape[1]
    return c
```

dimensions:

```
X_train : 784x60000
W1: 100x784
b1: 100x1
W2: 40x100
b2: 40x1
W3: 10x40
b3: 10x1
```

My cost seems to decrease for a while and then starts oscillating around some point and my accuracy doesn't increase at all. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you please add the dimensions of the inputs? It's hard to debug without these info.

Comment: If your cost is oscillating then it is probably that your learning rate is still too high. You should switch to a decaying learning rate, but watch out for overfitting.

Comment: I've added the dimensions @kmario23 . Please have a look at it.

Comment: I am decaying my learning rate after each iteration now @David . The cost seems to go down instead of oscillating. But still My accuracy doesn't improve.

Comment: What is your accuracy? It's clear that you are trying this on MNIST, which may help us if you confirm that.

Comment: Yes I am trying this on MNIST and the accuracy varies around .09 to .11 which means (and I've checked), it's all predicted outputs are same. @David

Comment: Start by making your model just one layer and slightly larger and see how well it performs then move on from there. Are you doing any preprocessing on the MNIST data?

Comment: @tahsin314 what're `z1_s, z2_s, z3_s`? Are these the tensors after applying sigmoid non-linearity?

Comment: Oops, those are from my old code. I've edited them @kmario23. I've replaced `z1_s z2_s z3_s` with `z1 z2 z3` but forgot to update my code snippet here. Thanks for noticing.